# How to stop adding items to the arraylist?

Tags: android, listview, items

There are 2 tabs expense and income. Expense tab and Income tab contains different listviews. When starting the activity with expense tab, list shows the database string array items. If there are 3 items in list, after switching the tab to Income tab and back to expense tab It will show 6 items. Adding again the same values into list. How to override this? Here is my code..

```
String[] theCategory;
String[] theMoneyType;
String[] theDescp;
String[] theDate;
String[] theAmount;

AllDataClass allData;

ListView exList;
private ArrayList<String> kId = new ArrayList<String>();           
private ArrayList<String> t_category = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_date = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_amount=new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_moneytype=new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_description=new ArrayList<String>();     <<< these array list values getting from SQlite database 

ArrayList<AllExpense> list=new ArrayList<AllExpense>();

theCategory=t_category.toArray(new String[t_category.size()]);

    theDate=t_date.toArray(new String[t_date.size()]);

    theAmount=t_amount.toArray(new String[t_amount.size()]);
    theMoneyType=t_moneytype.toArray(new String[t_moneytype.size()]);

    theDescp=t_description.toArray(new String[t_description.size()]);

    for(int i=0;i<theDate.length;i++) <<<<<< //this loop running again after switching the tab. I need this loop only one time.>>>>>>>>>>>
    {

        AllExpense ae=new AllExpense(theCategory[i],theDate[i],theAmount[i],theMoneyType[i],theDescp[i]);

        list.add(ae);

    }
```

Comment: either clear the array or check if array.contains(value);

Comment: Don't use the same array for both? Create a class called Transaction or something you like that keeps track of an array, give it all the methods you define now and use two separate instances of the class to keep track of both expense and income.

Comment: is my solution worked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear list before adding items.

```
list.clear();

for(int i=0;i<theDate.length;i++) <<<<<< //this loop running again after switching the tab. I need this loop only one time.>>>>>>>>>>>
    {

        AllExpense ae=new AllExpense(theCategory[i],theDate[i],theAmount[i],theMoneyType[i],theDescp[i]);

        list.add(ae);

    }
```

Comment: Yes.. This is what I m looking for.. Thanks a lot @H4SN

Answer (score 0):

write method to for validating weather strings are available or not

you also use

```
list.clear();
```

Before for loop

Answer (score 0):

check before adding:

```
private void test() {
    ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> totalNames=db.getAllNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNames.size(); i++) {
        if(!names.contains(totalNames.get(i))){
            names.add(totalNames.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another option would be

```
if(!list.IsEmpty()) {
    for(int i=0;i<theDate.length;i++)
    {
     ......
    }
}
```